# Error exporting interface

Tags: javascript, flowtype

If I import a Interface, flow does not recognize it, but If the interface is declared in the same file, it works as expected.

Working example:

```
interface Action {
  execute(): Promise < any > ;
}

class CreateJuridicalPerson {
  constructor() {}



  static create() {
      return new CreateJuridicalPerson();
  }

}

(new CreateJuridicalPerson: Action);

//[flow] [flow] property `execute` of Action (Property not found in CreateJuridicalPerson)
```

Failing example:

Action.js:

```
interface Action {
    execute(): Promise < any > ;
}
export default Action;
```

CreateJurdicalPerson.js:

```
import Action from './Action'

class CreateJuridicalPerson {
  constructor() {}



  static create() {
      return new CreateJuridicalPerson();
  }

}

(new CreateJuridicalPerson: Action);

//quiet...
```

Comment: My suggestion is to avoid interfaces between modules, you can use classes too. \*And interfaces aren't importable since they're abstract.\*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is invalid and raises the following error

```
src/Action.js:7
  7: export default Action;
                    ^^^^^^ Action. type referenced from value position
  3: interface Action {
     ^ type Action
```

If you are using Nuclide and you don't see the error, try to run `flow check` from the command line. The problem is that types and interfaces must be exported with `export type` or `export interface` and then imported with `import type`

Action.js

```
// @flow

export interface Action {
  execute(): Promise<any>;
}
```

index.js

```
// @flow

import type { Action } from './Action'

class CreateJuridicalPerson {
  constructor() {}
  static create() {
    return new CreateJuridicalPerson()
  }
}

(new CreateJuridicalPerson: Action)

src/index.js:12
 12: (new CreateJuridicalPerson: Action)
                                 ^^^^^^ property `execute` of Action. Property not found in
 12: (new CreateJuridicalPerson: Action)
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ CreateJuridicalPerson
```